# Having a Bit databind to a Checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox that is databound to a field in my database and that field is a bit in the database.

This is my Checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDownloaded" runat="server" Checked='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Downloaded")%>' />
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: @ryudice Yes, it is nullable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option #1

Your request to `Database` should be like below....

```
Select Cast(IsNull(Downloaded, 0) as bit) as Downloaded From TableName
```

### Option #2

In the `Business Logic Layer` `Convert` the `Downloaded` value to `false` in case of `Null`.

### Option #3

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox c = e.Row.FindControl("chkDownloaded");
    (((YourClassName)e.Row.DataItem).YourPropertyName) == null ? false : ((YourClassName)e.Row.DataItem).YourPropertyName;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Downloaded") ?? false
```

Answer (score 1):

you will have to convert it to boolean and bind

This way

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkDownloaded" 
runat="server" 
Checked='<%#Eval("Downloaded").ToString() == "1")%>' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Downloaded")!=0%>
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an ASP.NET expert, but if the column is nullable then

```
Checked='<%#(Eval("Downloaded") ?? 0).ToString() == "1")%>' />
```